# C# Pointer to correct LinkedListNode after LinkedList copying

Tags: c#, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Function with `LinkedList<T> list` and `LinkedListNode<T> current`

`current` is used as an anchor

```cs
public static void Foo<T>(
    LinkedList<T> list, 
    LinkedListNode<T> current
)
{
    var copy = new LinkedList<T>(list);
    copy.Remove(current);
    // Or some other action like copy.AddAfter(current, ...)
}

var list = new LinkedList<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var current = list.First;
Foo(list, current);
```

At `copy.Remove(current);`, current is not from copy, therefore this gives expection

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LinkedList node does not belong to current LinkedList.'
```

How can copy `LinkedList<T>` with `LinkedListNode<T> current` position information?

Any smart method that less than O(n)?

I know I can:

```cs
var copy_current = copy.Find(current.Value);
```

Please note that the main purpose of the question is not to remove `current`. This is want to copy/save information of LinkedLIstNode relative to the new LinkedList when copying. `current` may use for other actions like insert after, remove after.

To avoid [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem),

I am doing some destructive operations on LinkedList with `current` pointer, that will remove or add something on LinkedList, and sometimes I need to **rollback** the state (also rollback current pointer). Now I am considering record all operations and reverse.

Comment: Seems to be only possible with reflection, because all methods allowing you to do that I found are all internal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, when you do `var copy = new LinkedList<T>(list)` the new linked list does not preserve any relations with the old one.

The fundamental theorem of software engineering says: "[We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)"

So, you may create a wrapper class that holds this information:

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
var current = list.First;
Foo(list, current, 6);

static void Foo<T>(
    LinkedList<T> list,
    LinkedListNode<T> current,
    T value
)
{
    var copy = new Bridge<T>(list);
    _ = copy.AddAfter(current, value);
    _ = copy.AddBefore(current, value);
    copy.Remove(current);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", copy.InnerList));
}

class Bridge<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<LinkedListNode<T>, LinkedListNode<T>> _linkDictionary;

    public Bridge(LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        _linkDictionary = new Dictionary<LinkedListNode<T>, LinkedListNode<T>>();

        InnerList = new LinkedList<T>();

        // Code below reproduces the CopyTo behavior from 
        // the sources of LinkedList, see: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#L187-L192
        var linkedListNode = list.First;
        if (linkedListNode == null)
            return;
        do
        {
            var destNode = InnerList.AddLast(linkedListNode.Value);
            _linkDictionary.Add(linkedListNode, destNode);
            linkedListNode = linkedListNode.Next;
        }
        while (linkedListNode != null);
    }

    public LinkedList<T> InnerList { get; }

    public LinkedListNode<T> AddAfter(LinkedListNode<T> currentSource, T value)
    {
        var currentDest = _linkDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(currentSource) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Node not found.");
        return InnerList.AddAfter(currentDest, value);
    }

    public LinkedListNode<T> AddBefore(LinkedListNode<T> currentSource, T value)
    {
        var currentDest = _linkDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(currentSource) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Node not found.");
        return InnerList.AddBefore(currentDest, value);
    }

    public void Remove(LinkedListNode<T> currentSource)
    {
        var currentDest = _linkDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(currentSource) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Node not found.");
        InnerList.Remove(currentDest);
    }
}
```